# Fibration induced by cofibration: Still surjective?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fibration

On "Concised Course of Algebraic Topology", a fibration is defined to be surjective. And there is a proposition:

> If $i:A\to X$ is a cofibration and $B$ is a space, then the induced map $p=B^i:B^X\to B^A$ is a fibration.

I know in category of compactly closed spaces, a cofibration is injective with closed image. But I want to know this implies $p=B^i$ is surjective.

Comment: Let $i: S^1 \rightarrow D^2$ be the inclusion of the boundary of the 2-disk. Then You may be aware that the identity map $S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ does not extend to a map $D^2 \rightarrow S^1$. Letting $B=S^1$ we obtain a counterexample to your statement.

Comment: Have a look at May's comments at the very top of pg. 19 of his follow up book *More Concise Algebraic Topology*, where he notes that the assertion you cite above was incorrectly stated in his eariler book.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one has yet answered your question, I'll type up what is basically the answer Noel Lundström left in the comments, and try to add a little of my own knowledge for context.

Firstly it should be pointed out that fibrations need not be surjective in general. Indeed, in his follow up book, *More Concise Algebraic Topology*, May writes;

> "Observe that a fibration $p:E\rightarrow B$ need not be surjective (In [A Concise Course of Algebraic Topology], fibrations were incorrectly required to be surjective maps), but either ever point or no point of each component of $B$ is in the image of $E$."

Hopefully this should go some way to correcting your disatisfaction. In particular, when $B$ is path connected, then any fibration $p:E\rightarrow B$ is surjective.

For some examples of where a fibration might be non-surjective we have the following.

$\bullet$ For any space $X$, the unique map $\emptyset\rightarrow X$ is an unpointed (Hurewicz) fibration. Clearly this map is very rarely surjective.

$\bullet$ Michael Albanese's suggestion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2893986/surjectivity-of-hurewicz-fibrations/2894040#2894040) of adding additional path components to $B$ without altering $E$.

$\bullet$ Noel Lundström's suggestion from the comments: the inclusion $i:S^1\hookrightarrow D^2$ is a closed cofibration and so the induced map $i^*:(S^1)^{D^2}\rightarrow (S^1)^{S^1}$ has the homotopy lifting property for formal reasons. A point $f\in (S^1)^{S^1}$ is a map $\ast\rightarrow (S^1)^{S^1}$ (working in the unpointed context), and by adjunction this is the same as a map $\widehat f:S^1\rightarrow S^1$. Then the $f$ is in the image of $i^*$ if and only if $\widehat f$ admits an extension to $D^2$. But the only time that this can happen is when $\widehat f$ is null-homotopic, and clearly not every map $S^1\rightarrow S^1$ is null-homotopic. Hence $i^*$ cannot be surjective.