# For $p: (E, e_0) \to (B, b_0)$ a Hurewicz fibration, is the inclusion $p^{-1}(b_0) \to E$ a Hurewicz fibration as well?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fibration

As $p$ is a Hurewicz fibration, its homotopy fiber $hofib_{b_0}(p)$ is homotopy equivalent to $p^{-1}(b_0)$, but does this also mean that the map $p^{-1}(b_0) \to E$ is a Hurewicz fibration as well?

Comment: Aren't Hurewicz fibrations required to be surjective? More over, for any weak notion of fibration we should have that the fiber is weakly equivalent to the homotopy fiber. Since the map you describe is constant the homotopy fiber is $\Omega B \times p^{-1}(b) $ which is usually not equivalent to $p^{-1}(b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For example, the identity $id : (\mathbb R, 0) \to (\mathbb R, 0)$ is a Hurewicz fibration, but the inclusion $\{0\} = id^{-1}(0) \to \mathbb R$ is not. See [Surjectivity of Hurewicz fibrations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2893986): For a Hurewicz fibration $p : E \to B$ the set $p(E)$ is a union of path components of $B$.